# npm installs dependencies on a different depth level

Tags: npm

I have a "eslint-config" module published as a github repo. It has such dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "15.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.0.1"
  },
```

In another empty project **"estest"** I installed this module as a single dev dependency:

```
npm i -D github:MyTeam/eslint-config
```

The command produced the output:

```
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@15.0.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.19.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.3.0 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 3.x but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@5.0.3 requires a peer of eslint@^2.10.2 || 3.x but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.0.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@11.2.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.19.0 but none was installed.

+ eslint-config@1.0.0
added 203 packages in 13.898s
```

It acts like `eslint` module was not installed.
If I look inside `estest/node_modules` I see that structure:

```
node_modules
  eslint-config // <-- this is my module
    node_modules
      eslint // <-- it has only one dep installed inside
  // all other `eslint-config` deps are flat-installed into root:
  babel-eslint
  eslint-config-airbnb 
  eslint-plugin-import
  eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
  eslint-plugin-react
  ...
```

So all `eslint-config` dependencies were flat-installed into root `node_modules` except `eslint`. And because of this some of them complains that peer dependency is missing.

And `npm ls` command shows `eslint` as unmet peer dep:

```
└─┬ eslint-config@1.0.0 
  ├─┬ babel-eslint@7.2.3
  ├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@3.19.0
  ├─┬ eslint-config-airbnb@15.0.1
  │ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@^3.19.0
  │ └── eslint-config-airbnb-base@11.2.0
  ├─┬ eslint-plugin-import@2.3.0
  │ ├─┬ eslint-import-resolver-node@0.2.3
  │ ├─┬ eslint-module-utils@2.1.1
  ├─┬ eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@5.0.3
  └─┬ eslint-plugin-react@7.0.1
```

I want to be able to just install `eslint-config` dependency and do not install `eslint` separately. How to do it?

Comment: I though adding them as both peerDeps and deps would move the packages up the tree but I just ran into a package that does not (and is not a dep of anything else) so this must not be a guaranteed solution. You can check out yarn's 'flat' but i don't want to switch you yarn over this.